# Windows Azure App Service: recover lost source code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to recover lost source code from Azure App Service?

I Had my source code in a external SDD, but when it was doing a build to deploy the code, the SDD stopped the connection to the computer and the entire SDD was compromised. Despite it asks to format to read the SDD, I tried to recover all data without formating and ended up seeing every files in the SDD... the problem is that the source code isnt anywhere to be found.

So at this moment I lost some months of development (i know i should do backups more often :(... ). I deployed my projects with Visual Studio...

Does anyone know how to find the source code (if any), or if it is possible to get it from the .ddl .pdb files. I didnt have blob configured, so I dont know if Visual Studio does a back up anywhere else.

Can somebody help me if possible? thanks

Comment: I answered this near-exact-same question yesterday, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37845355/272109).

Comment: Exact same case, thank you, didnt find that question in my searches... regards!

Comment: Oh by the way, I dont think that the answer is that strait forward... there are cases where Visual Studio with Azure creates a copy of the files to blob, and then publish them... as you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574621/windows-azure-cloud-service-recover-lost-source-code  and here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj154121.aspx , your answer isnt entirely true, because if it is true that c# publishes .dll (not just the .dll, there is content that is publishes as is), it is also true that there are mecanisms to prevent data lost. I asked for those...

Comment: No, that StackOverflow question you referenced is for Cloud Services (web and worker roles), where the `.cspkg` package file is pushed to blob first. And even in that case, source files aren't pushed - only binaries (or whatever you choose to copy-local in your output directory).  Your question (and the one I marked it as duplicate of) is specific to Web Apps, and there's no intermediate blob holding anything regarding deployment.

Comment: And no, there's no way to magically extract source files from dll's (aside from a disassembly, but even that does not translate into a native source file). Any type of file recovery you perform would be related to disk recovery tools, something that's out-of-scope / off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I know that the questions I pointed arent for App Services, thats why I asked if it could be something similar to it for App Services. If it was the same, the questions would be answered in those :). Your answer pointed that part of a possible solution (getting the code from .dll, for ex) was not possible -> Thanks :). The other part, the interaction between VS and Azure, wasnt scoped at it, so at that moment, to me, it was incompleted. BTW, saying that Vs only pushes binary is wrong. You have the Content, Views, CSS, scripts, images, themes, configs, that are pushed as source codes.C#==binary

Comment: Oh, but dont get me wrong, thank you very much for your answer and your time :). Regards